# (How) can I specify non-Docker hub image to be used for services with gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How can I specify the image to be used by a service in gitlab-ci.yml?

This is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855241/gitlab-ci-service-and-docker-hub-auth), where the answer was basically a very thorough copy and paste RTFM.

I am using Gitlab runners on AWS EKS using gitlab's autodeploy.
Logging into the gitlab-runner, I had added

```
environment = ["FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE=1"]
```

to `/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`
This seemed to reduce the number of pulls to Docker. However, it seems that calls to

```
services:
    - mongo:latest
```

are really eating up the allowance of Docker pulls. If the aforementioned documentation specifies how to authenticate with Docker for pulling images used in services or how to specify a private repository for services, I did not see it.

I tried adding `${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}` to the service specification i.e.
services:

- ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/mongo:latest

but that just broke the database checks - or at least didn't fix the issues with Docker's rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up removing the services from the `gitlab-ci.yml` file and just running the services with the pipeline by declaring the private images in
`/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` :

```
[[runners.kubernetes.services]]
        name = "gitlabexample.com/ourgroup/ourproject/mongo"
        alias = "mongo"
```